# NavigationDrawerActivity showing fragments with and without tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, navigation-drawer

I have a NavigationDrawerActivity with the following XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You can see that the Activity contains the TabLayout within its AppBarLayout as demonstrated in many tutorials/code examples.
The FrameLayout `fl_fragment_container` is replaced with the content fragment which the user selects in the navigation drawer.

My question is **how to show/hide the `TabLayout` depending on the current content fragment?** and in succession **how to communicate between the TabLayout and the content fragment?**

I could put the tabs into each content fragment, but then the AppBarLayout would elevate above it, so I could not achieve the desired MaterialDesign where the tabs are part of the AppBarLayout.

Comment: You can do it by using Interface

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this answers only the 2nd question.

Comment: I think if you communicate with tablayout then also  you can show/hide it